# Looking for library declaration of IP Module

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I want to use the Xilinx hardware module of the ICAP controller in my own design.
This module uses the following library:

```
library hwicap_v5_00_a;
use hwicap_v5_00_a.all;
```

I was looking in the directories as well as subdirectories of

```
Xilinx\12.1\ISE_DS\EDK\hw\XilinxProcessorIPLib\pcores
```

but I could not find the package declaration of hwicap. Anyone an idea where Xilinx "hides" this information.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you just compile all the VHDL files from

`C:\Xilinx\12.3\ISE_DS\EDK\hw\XilinxProcessorIPLib\pcores\hwicap_v5_00_a\hdl\vhdl`

into a library called `hwicap_v5_00_a`  - this is the way EDK works.

There's no package that I can see.